# How to push the json to the array state of Mobx in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I am using mobx in React now with firebase.
First, there is a 'projectState' as a empty array.
Second, after get the data from firestore, it is pushed into the state of Mobx.
This is a code of mine.

```
 @observable projectState = {
    projects: []
  };

  projectGet = () => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("projects")
      .doc("DkBFcdAOAWWl8Az")
      .get()
      .then(done => {
        const projectsTotal = JSON.stringify(done.data());
        this.projectState.projects.push(projectsTotal);

      });
  };
```

'done.data()' gives the json type file like below.

```
{"id": "3", "title": "good"}
```

However, when I use 'console.log' to check the state after pushing data.
it gives me like below.

```
   Proxy {0: "{"content":"asdf","id":"123","title":"yoman"}", 
1: "{"content":"asdf","id":"123","title":"yoman"}",
 Symbol(mobx administration): ObservableArrayAdministration}
```

How can I push the json data well into the mobx state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are converting the returned object into a string when you `const projectsTotal = JSON.stringify(done.data());`

You can change it to only assign the data.

```
 @observable projectState = {
    projects: []
  };

  projectGet = () => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("projects")
      .doc("DkBFcdAOAWWl8Az")
      .get()
      .then(done => {
        this.projectState.projects.push(done.data());
      });
  };
```

In addition, from the stringified values, I see that Firebase returns an object literal, you probably what to convert it into an array and push each item separately.

You can use `Object.values` to get an array of values.

```
@observable projectState = {
    projects: []
  };

  projectGet = () => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("projects")
      .doc("DkBFcdAOAWWl8Az")
      .get()
      .then(done => {
        Object.values(done.data())
              .forEach((value) => {this.projectState.projects.push(value)});
      });
  };
```

Comment: Thank  you so much. But when I after push, use console.log(this.projectState.projects) gives "Proxy {0: Proxy, Symbol(mobx administration): ObservableArrayAdministration}". So there isn't a pure json file like '{"A":"b"} inside of the project state. 
Could you help me this problem?

Comment: I attached your code in my code. But the result is same. T.T

Comment: And what are the values in the array after the iteration?

Comment: It works well after editing a little bit more. Thank your for your insight.